# How may I avoid ParametricPlot3D clipping?

Tags: plotting

What I am doing:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[z/2]^6 * Cos[t],Cos[z/2]^6 *  Sin[t], z}, {t,-Pi, Pi},{z,-Pi,Pi}]
```

What I get:

[image]

What I want: what I get, but without the clipping that creates the hole.

Comment: Add `PlotRange -> All` to the end

Comment: As I see it, your question was in no way specific to the use of the cloud, so I have removed it.

Comment: "your question was in no way specific to the use of the cloud" Did you actually test the code on non-cloud platforms, or did you just assume that? I have restored the tag.

Comment: "This question arises due to a simple mistake" Incorrect. "easily found in the documentation" That doesn't make it off topic. See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic . "This question appears to be off-topic for this site" is false and this question should not be on hold.

Comment: I think it's safe to say that I have *some* experience with using `ParametricPlot3D[]`, considering that I was already using it back when it was a function that had to be loaded through a package. And yes, you are not the first special snowflake to be sideswiped by *Mathematica* trying to guess the "best features" of your plot and then clipping the plot range accordingly.

Comment: Further discussion of "off-topic" nature is at http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1619/whats-behind-false-question-characterisations-such-as-this-one .

Comment: "This question already has an answer here" Actually not. That's a very different question, and its problem has a different cause.

Comment: "I think it's safe to say that I have some experience with using ParametricPlot3D[]" I asked if you tested the code on non-cloud.. From the fact you didn't answer, I'll assume No.

Comment: @Guess, Patrick Re the meta, please contribute to my question: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/is-the-wolfram-programming-cloud-tag-appropriate-for-a-question-that-is-specific

Comment: FTR, the false characterisation of this question as "off-topic" has now been rescinded. Thanks to whoever did that.

Comment: @Chris Do you have any evidence that it does not work on non-cloud platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supply the option `PlotRange -> All`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[z/2]^6*Cos[t], Cos[z/2]^6*Sin[t], z}, 
                 {t, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}, 
                 PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. That works fine. Now I see the default behaviour of this function is defined as "outlying points are dropped". Goodness know why anyone thought that was a good idea! :) Likewise to the fact that it is asymmetric w.r.t. x and y.

Comment: The defaults are to display axes scaled to the golden ratio, I believe. Similarly, "drop outlying points" behaviour is decidedly wanted in some cases, like if an outlier would make all other features invisible due to scale. Good heuristics are extremely hard to find.

Comment: Patrick, that's an interesting rep number that you have… :)

Comment: Now you mention it, I've been feeling a bit evil recently. Might just go and indulge in some brimstone.

Comment: The "golden ratio" scaling is for `Plot[]`/`ListPlot[]`. `ParametricPlot3D[]` has the `BoxRatios -> Automatic` setting by default.

Comment: @Chris Forgive me for quoting the documentation for `ParametricPlot3D` which you've probably read: "Automatic `PlotRange` depends on parametrization."  In other words, it's a mystery. :)